# R: Merging 2 data frames with index on previous and past rows

Tags: r, loops, date, merge

Lets say I have a dataset like this:

```
origin=data.frame(Date=as.Date(c("2016-08-05","2016-08-04","2016-08-03")),
                  L=c(1,2,3),
                  Type=c("H","L","H"))

        Date L Type
1 2016-08-05 1    H
2 2016-08-04 2    L
3 2016-08-03 3    H

end=data.frame(Date=as.Date(c("2016-08-05","2016-08-04","2016-08-03","2016-08-02","2016-08-01")),
               N=c(50,40,30,20,10),
               Name=c("CA","CB","CC","CD","CE"),
               Vol=c(2,1,2,2,3),
               Act=c(0.1,0.2,0.3,0.2,0.2))

        Date  N Name Vol Act
1 2016-08-05 50   CA   2 0.1
2 2016-08-04 40   CB   1 0.2
3 2016-08-03 30   CC   2 0.3
4 2016-08-02 20   CD   2 0.2
5 2016-08-01 10   CE   3 0.2
```

I want something like this:

```
        Date L Type  N Name Vol Act
3 2016-08-05 1    H 50   CA   2 0.1
3 2016-08-05 1    H 40   CB   1 0.2
3 2016-08-05 1    H 30   CC   2 0.3
2 2016-08-04 2    L 40   CB   1 0.2
2 2016-08-04 2    L 30   CC   2 0.3
2 2016-08-04 2    L 20   CD   2 0.2
1 2016-08-03 3    H 30   CC   2 0.3
1 2016-08-03 3    H 20   CD   2 0.2
1 2016-08-03 3    H 10   CE   3 0.2
```

I want to maintain the original column date of "origin", and in the merge, I want to merge it with the current and previous dates values of "end"(the 2 previous values), like a sort of merge with a loop. In other posts, only the common values are matched, which gives the 3 rows result:

```
merge(x = origin, y = end, by = "Date")

        Date L Type  N Name Vol Act
1 2016-08-03 3    H 30   CC   2 0.3
2 2016-08-04 2    L 40   CB   1 0.2
3 2016-08-05 1    H 50   CA   2 0.1
```

Which is very different, and doesn't merge the two data frames by the current and previous row values, so I am unable to figure out how to go about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `foverlaps` from `data.table` is a suit for this job:

```
# prepare data and add extra columns for foverlaps join which relies on columns instead of one
library(data.table)
setDT(origin)[, DateStart := Date - 2]
setDT(end)[, DateStart := Date]
setkey(origin, DateStart, Date)

# join two tables with foverlaps and remove subsidiary columns
foverlaps(end, origin, type = "within")[, `:=` (DateStart = NULL, i.Date = NULL, i.DateStart = NULL)][order(Date)]

#          Date L Type  N Name Vol Act
# 1: 2016-08-03 3    H 30   CC   2 0.3
# 2: 2016-08-03 3    H 20   CD   2 0.2
# 3: 2016-08-03 3    H 10   CE   3 0.2
# 4: 2016-08-04 2    L 40   CB   1 0.2
# 5: 2016-08-04 2    L 30   CC   2 0.3
# 6: 2016-08-04 2    L 20   CD   2 0.2
# 7: 2016-08-05 1    H 50   CA   2 0.1
# 8: 2016-08-05 1    H 40   CB   1 0.2
# 9: 2016-08-05 1    H 30   CC   2 0.3
```

Or use `non-equi` join feature of `data.table` version `1.9.7`:

```
setDT(origin)[, `:=` (DateEnd = Date, StartDate = Date - 2)]
             [setDT(end), on = .(DateEnd >= Date, StartDate <= Date), allow = T]

#          Date L Type    DateEnd  StartDate  N Name Vol Act
# 1: 2016-08-05 1    H 2016-08-05 2016-08-05 50   CA   2 0.1
# 2: 2016-08-04 2    L 2016-08-04 2016-08-04 40   CB   1 0.2
# 3: 2016-08-05 1    H 2016-08-04 2016-08-04 40   CB   1 0.2
# 4: 2016-08-03 3    H 2016-08-03 2016-08-03 30   CC   2 0.3
# 5: 2016-08-04 2    L 2016-08-03 2016-08-03 30   CC   2 0.3
# 6: 2016-08-05 1    H 2016-08-03 2016-08-03 30   CC   2 0.3
# 7: 2016-08-03 3    H 2016-08-02 2016-08-02 20   CD   2 0.2
# 8: 2016-08-04 2    L 2016-08-02 2016-08-02 20   CD   2 0.2
# 9: 2016-08-03 3    H 2016-08-01 2016-08-01 10   CE   3 0.2
```

Remove subsidiary columns should be straightforward.

Comment: This actually solved my problem. But I didn't realize that the data frames I proposed here were not fully reflecting the problem. Actually, I need to merge 2 data frames, but the second one has multiple columns(up to 10), and I need up to 5 lags. So I am rectifying the question, to fully reflect that case.